# Castle 3.0 ILogger breaks the NVelocityTemplateEngine wrapper?

Tags: castle-windsor, nvelocity

It appears that the the ILogger interface in 3.x is missing a method for .Info that the TemplateEngineNeeds.  I'm getting the following error...

```
Method not found: 'Void Castle.Core.Logging.ILogger.Info(System.String, System.Object[])'.
```

I'm using version 1.1.1.0 Castle.Components.Common.TemplateEngine.NVelocityTemplateEngine.  Perhaps this isn't the correct version so any help in pointing out the correct version would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know nobody has upgraded TemplateEngine to Castle.Core 3.0 yet. Please [fork the repository](https://github.com/castleproject/Attic) and upgrade it, then send the team a pull request. If you have any questions about the code post to the [Castle Dev list](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel).

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I did find the line of code that causes the error.  I've not done any forking of projects within github so I'll read up on that and do it over the next few days.

Comment: After reviewing this a bit further, it looks to me like the real problem is that the ILogger interface was changed between versions.  There is a missing method overload for Info.  Wouldn't it be more appropriate to fix the interface?

Comment: @Steven I recommend asking on the Castle dev list http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel Please include all relevant details about this: what changed, if possible when (what commit), what change do you propose.